# CSS Matrix - how to achieve percentage translation

Tags: css, transform

My chrome debugger tells me these are all invalid rules

```
transform: scale(1.1,1.1),translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,-50%,-50%);
```

How do I apply both a scale and percentage translation transform to a single element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  transform: scale(1.1,1.1) translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```